# UIImageView in UITableViewCell resizes to row height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UITableViewCell and I am using it's UIImageView and I have an image of size 25,25 that I set the UIImageView with. The issue is that when I tap on the cell, the image size resizes to the row height, which is not what I wanted. I wanted it to stay fix at 25,25. Is this possible? Here's my code:

```
  cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(cell.imageView.origin.x, cell.imageView.origin.y, 25, 25);
        cell.imageView.frame = cell.imageView.bounds;
        cell.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
        cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but you have to create your own UITableViewCell by subclass UITableViewCell and add UIImageView with your fixed size

Comment: What if I wanted to use the built in UIImageView?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to resize UIImageView integrated to the default tableViewCell, if you want to do that you must use your custom UITableViewCell, http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html can help you